# Stack Overflow error (infinite loop ?) during GWT compilation

Tags: gwt, compiler-construction

I've been doing mvn clean install on my GWT projet for months, and now it is broken. I get the following stack trace:

```
[INFO]    Compiling 3 permutations
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 1...
[INFO]       Process output
[INFO]          Compiling
[INFO]             Compiling permutation 0...
[INFO]       Process output
[INFO]          Compiling
[INFO]             Compiling permutation 2...
[INFO]       [ERROR] StackOverflowError: Increase stack size
[INFO] java.lang.StackOverflowError
[INFO]  at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:322)
[INFO]  at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:94)
[INFO]  at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:426)
[INFO]  at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:443)
[INFO]  at java.io.PrintWriter.print(PrintWriter.java:587)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.AbstractTextOutput.printAndCount(AbstractTextOutput.java:148)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.AbstractTextOutput.print(AbstractTextOutput.java:107)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor._nameRef(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:1190)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:723)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsNameRef.traverse(JsNameRef.java:117)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsSourceGenerationVisitorWithSizeBreakdown.generateAndBill(JsSourceGenerationVisitorWithSizeBreakdown.java:119)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsReportGenerationVisitor.generateAndBill(JsReportGenerationVisitor.java:58)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsSourceGenerationVisitorWithSizeBreakdown.doAccept(JsSourceGenerationVisitorWithSizeBreakdown.java:96)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:672)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsInvocation.traverse(JsInvocation.java:69)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
```

As you can see I only have 3 permutations. The last lines of the output (the `com.google.gwt.dev.js` stuff) are repeated tens of times (I didn't paste everything) which make me think this might be related to some infinite loop.

After the stack overflow error is printed, I get the rest of the stack trace as follow:

```
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:325)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsBinaryOperation.traverse(JsBinaryOperation.java:112)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Stack overflow; to increase the stack size, use the -Xss flag at startup (java -Xss1M ...)
[INFO]       [ERROR] Unrecoverable exception, shutting down
[INFO] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory$ThreadedPermutationWorker.compile(ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory.java:60)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.PermutationWorkerFactory$Manager$WorkerThread.run(PermutationWorkerFactory.java:73)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[INFO]       [ERROR] Not all permutation were compiled , completed (0/3)
[INFO]       [WARN] Lost communication with remote process
[INFO] java.net.SocketException: socket closed
[INFO]  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
[INFO]  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
[INFO]  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:203)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2559)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2569)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1315)
[INFO]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.ExternalPermutationWorkerFactory$ExternalPermutationWorker.compile(ExternalPermutationWorkerFactory.java:152)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.PermutationWorkerFactory$Manager$WorkerThread.run(PermutationWorkerFactory.java:73)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[INFO]       [WARN] Lost communication with remote process
[INFO] java.net.SocketException: socket closed
[INFO]  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
```

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Please post your code. Have you changed something recently, maybe something which can produce this error?

Comment: Thanks for helping. We are 6 people working on this project. It's been a while since I had to do a clean install. The possibilities are enormous... The problem happens during GWT compilation. Maybe someone with insights in the GWT compiler could give me a lead ?

Comment: Are you using distributed compilation?

Comment: No, everything happens in one batch on a single computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to set higher values for the JVM arguments inside the GWT-Maven-Plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
      <executions>
          <execution>
             <configuration>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
              </configuration>
...
```

That's it.